# Cant figure out the output of the expression

Tags: constraints, expression, equation

Can anyone explain or provide reference to

ai X aj <= max(Ai + Ai+1 + .. + Aj)

I am unable to figure out the output of this expression, can you provide any explanation or example please.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Asking for the details on 

Can anyone explain or provide reference to

ai * aj =< max(Ai + Ai+1 + .. + Aj) function how to interpret it